# How to adjust cells as per the content

Tags: datatable, datatables

You can see how my column which has long text is 'smashed'. How can I align all the column to be as wide as the content in it ? [image: table]

Comment: Have you investigated any general approaches, such as [preset widths](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width), [horizontal scrolling](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX)? You may need more advanced approaches ([such as this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive)) for some scenarios.

Comment: For a more targeted answer, a [mre] may be helpful.

Comment: Maybe max-width:100%; will help you.